# Calculate PDSI with R, it reports an error

Tags: r

Thanks for Stackoverflow, I got the package named cszang/pdsi from Github.
However, when i test with the data from this package, Rstudio reports an error.

```
 library(pdsi)
 library(bootRes)
 data(muc.clim)
 pdsi(12, 50, muc.clim, 1960, 2000)
```

Muc.clim is a data with climate parameters in the 'pdsi' package. 
Then Rstudio display this:

```
pdsi(12, 50, muc.clim, 1960, 2000)
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.3/library/pdsi/exec/sc-pdsi.exe  
-m -i "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/6d74a6d0de96f31dc5d695076d0492a6" 
1960 2000' had status 127 
2: In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 
'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/6d74a6d0de96f31dc5d695076d0492a6/monthly/
self_cal/PDSI.tbl': No such file or directory
```

I don`t know why its shows this, I search for 'PDSI.tbl'. The document named 'scpdsi.cpp' define it with "The Palmer Drought Severity Index values", the two related codes was

```
//remove any existing output files:
sprintf(filename,"%s%s",dir,"PDSI.tbl");
remove(filename);
sprintf(filename,"%s%s",dir,"PDSI.clm");
remove(filename);
```

and

```
// If output_mode is 0 or 2 the table files are opened for writing
if(output_mode==0 || output_mode==2) {
//open files
sprintf(filename,"%s%s",dir,"PDSI.tbl");
pdsi0=fopen(filename,"w");
sprintf(filename,"%s%s",dir,"PHDI.tbl");
phdi0=fopen(filename,"w");
```

Please help me solve this, or is there any other packages can calculate PDSI for many years. Thank you !!